# Edit Pentaho PUC's vertical side menu

Tags: html, jsp, pentaho

We're doing customization on Pentaho Community 7.0 user console but we got stuck on the left vertical menu, specifically this one:

[image: Pentaho PUC vertical menu]

We can't find the JSP files generating this HTML. We did searches on the entire Pentaho folder structure to search inside files, researched the web for something but aparently nobody could modify these buttons.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

If not, is there a way to inspect what JSP files are generating what HTML?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked `biserver-ce/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/mantle/home/index.jsp`? In CE 5.0 it looks very similar to what you need. Or in 7.1 souces: https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform/blob/7.1/user-console/src/main/resources/org/pentaho/mantle/public/home/index.jsp#L124

Comment: @user4637357 yeah I've found this file but we have no JSP knowledge, I can't seem to find from where its pulling it's text values (I see no strings in the code so I deduce they're being pulled from another file).

Comment: TBH, I don't know jsp either, but as far as I know, the jsp contains strings like `{{i18n.browse}}` - the value will be substituted with value identified with `browse` key from `mantle/home/properties/messages.properties` file. (Or from messages_en or messages_fr - depending on user's settings).

Comment: @user4637357 Yey, it worked! Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can choose it as a solution? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pentaho user console side-bar is defined in `biserver-ce/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/mantle/home/i‌​ndex.jsp` file ([the file in github](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform/blob/7.1/user-console/src/main/resources/org/pentaho/mantle/public/home/index.jsp#L124)).

The jsp contains strings like `{{i18n.browse}}` - this value will be substituted with the value identified with `browse` key from `mantle/home/properties/messages.properties` file ([the file in github](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-platform/blob/7.1/user-console/src/main/resources/org/pentaho/mantle/public/home/properties/messages.properties)). Alternatively, values may come from the localized files: `messages_en.properties` or `messages_fr.properties`, etc - depending on the user's settings).